# Update progressbar from nested Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, progress-bar

I am rewriting some code to use TPL instead of BackgroundWorkers and implementing multi-threading at the same time. I have everything running fine (runs in parallel and cancellation works as well) but cannot figure out how to update my progressbar appropriately. This is what I have so far (not going to write the full task since it's pretty big):

UPDATE: I have updated the code with the changes I have tried from some of the suggestions.

```
var progressHandler = new Progress<int>(value => { pgbOverviewProgressbar.Value = value; });
progress = progressHandler as IProgress<int>;

await Task.Run(() => taskGetOverviewData(ct), ct);

public void taskGetOverviewData(CancellationToken ct)
{
    DateTime dtTime2 = DateTime.Now;
    int totalcount = lstDKCZ.Count * lstPTST.Count;
    double iCounter = 0;

    Parallel.ForEach(lstDKCZ, item =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(lstPTST, item2 =>
                {
                    //Lots of SQL queries and whatnot

                    double iCount = overview.Count();

                    foreach(var item3 in overview)
                    {
                        //Again lots of things happening

                        if (DateTime.Now > dtTime2.AddMilliseconds(15))
                        {
                            if (iCounter != iCount)
                                progress.Report(Convert.ToInt32((iCounter / iCount) * 100 / totalcount);

                            dtTime2 = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                    }
              }
       }
}
```

A maximum of 4 parallel iterations are carried out (2 elements in lstDKCZ and 2 elements in lstPTST). This worked fine when doing the work sequentially, well kind of, since the progressbar would just run 4 times (and I just want it to run one time for the whole process). Now it just jumps up and down sporadically, but that is expected and easy enough to understand why (updating the same variable from 4 different threads).

But how do I approach this? I saw locking mentioned while searching for an answer, but I do not quite understand how to implement it in this scenario.

UPDATE 2: Make 4 different progress reports for each scenario. How to merge them?

```
if (DateTime.Now > dtTime2.AddMilliseconds(15))
{
    if (iCounter != iCount)
    {
        //Make 4 different of these for each scenario
        if (item == "DK" && item2 == "PT")
            progress1.Report(Convert.ToInt32((iCounter / iCount) * 100))                             
        dtTime2 = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Then what I would want (as far as I understand) is something like:

```
totalprogress = (progress1 + progress2 + progress3 + progress4) / totalcount;
```

I cannot seem to get this right though, as I cannot convert the progresses into an integer and pass that value to the totalprogress.

Comment: doesn't your bw have its  ProgressChanged event enabled?

Comment: Also: try to find a gauging scheme that can do with simply __adding__ to a value instead of __setting__ a value as the latter will not work well with parallel tasks..

Comment: I am no longer using backgroundworkers, hence why ProgressChanged events are no longer used.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. My other comment holds though: jumping up and down is a clear indication that each task tries to set a value instead of increasing it.

Comment: You need to know the total of all loops before you start your parallel for each and declare an increment variable at the same level. Then you can divide by that as you inner loop get incremented.

Comment: @TaW I am not sure I understand. If you mean just incrementing per iteration of the foreach loop, this is not possible since the amount of iterations can be huge. This would greatly decrease performance.

Could you explain what you mean further?

Comment: By gauge I mean find a formula to do just that: increment a totalwork variable. It can be a long or float or double if necessary, just scale it down when you set the progressBar's value. In parallel no task can know the totalwork, it can only report that one more unit of work has been done.. Of course you should only increase the totalwork variable in an outer loop and maybe also test to see if the calculated progressBar.Value actually changes before you hit on the UI..

Comment: Or you could update the like this: `pgbOverviewProgressbar.Value = Math.Max(pgbOverviewProgressbar.Value, value)`;

Comment: I tried out the Math.Max approach. Now the progressbar does not jump up and down. However, it fills too quickly as some of the work might be slower than others.

Comment: Tried out Math.Min instead, but then the progressbar is not filled at all.

Comment: What you really need is four different progress reports and merge them into a single combined one. Are the counts of `lstDKCZ` and `lstPTST` *always* two?

Comment: @StephenCleary No, but that is the maximum count for both of them. Neither of them can be empty as well. The number of processes can then only be 1, 2 or 4.

Comment: @StephenCleary I tried making four different progress reports now, but I have no idea how to merge them. Do I convert them into an integer or something?

Comment: @St0ffer: A weighted average should suffice. This is easiest if your four progresses each report a double in the range [0, 1] (thus "weighing" itself); then you can just make the combined report a double value - `progresses.Average()` if `progresses` is a list of the "child" progress reports.

Comment: @StephenCleary Sorry, as you might have noticed I am pretty new to multithreading and the lot.

So, I need to make a list of progresses like this? `List<Progress<double>> progresses = new List<Progress<double>>();`

Define a progress like: `IProgress<double> progress1 = new Progress<double>();`

Add it to the list?

`progresses.Add(progress1);`

I am missing something and I get an error saying it cannot add progress1 to the list.

Comment: Or is it something like adding the reported values to the list instead? `var progresshandler = new Progress<double>(value => { progresses.Add(value); });` Then have each progress like: `progress1 = progresshandler as IProgress<double>;` I am pretty lost to be honest.

Comment: How about if you start over and this time just replace `BackgroundWorker` with `Task.Run`?

Comment: Thing is, before when I used BGW I was not using Parallel.ForEach, and I definitely need to use it, as it greatly improves the performance. Before it was doing the work sequentially and therefore was a lot easier to report progress for. The thing that is hard for me is to figure out how to get this overall progress report to work, how to work with a list of progresses.

For now I have decided to just show a loading panel while work is being performed as it is not working out for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about if you divide the progress by the length of lstDKCZ and lstPTST?

```
int totalCount = lstDKCZ.Count * lstPTST.Count;
Parallel.ForEach(lstDKCZ, item =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(lstPTST, item2 =>
            {
                //Lots of SQL queries and whatnot

                double iCount = overview.Count();
                double iCounter = 0;

                foreach(var item3 in overview)
                {
                    //Again lots of things happening

                    if (DateTime.Now > dtTime2.AddMilliseconds(15))
                    {
                        if (iCounter != iCount)
                            progress.Report(Convert.ToInt32((iCounter / iCount) * 100 / totalCount);

                        dtTime2 = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }
          }
   }
```

Comment: I agree with this approach, but couldn't you make it even easier by having iTotalCompleteCount also and then iTotalCompleteCount/iTotalCount?

Comment: This won't work, as the progress will still be reported 4 times in parallel. The progressbar still jumps around like crazy. What I am trying to achieve is to make the progress bar update one time as an indication of the FULL work.

Comment: Looks like I wrote it wrong the first time I tried this out. Now it should be correct and it does look better now. It still jumps around though. Could it have something to do with one of the the iterations of the Parallel loop being slower than the others? Some of the SQL queries take more time than the others, since it's fetching data from an international server as opposed to getting the data from a local server. The difference lies in lstDKCZ, which basically holds up to two elements corresponding to two different SQL servers.

Comment: If you want to control the frequency of progressbar update, call progress.Report for every item (or several items), and inside the progress handler keep a timer that updates the UI every 100 ms or so with the latest value.